# ¿Es la palabra "parcero/a" un insulto en Colombia?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, coloquialismos, colombia

> —¡Hola! ¿Qué más?
>
> —¡Qué bacán, **parcero**, gracielas!

Alguien me dijo que llamar a alguien *parcero/a* es un insulto en Colombia. ¿Por qué es así?

Comment: Tal vez no quiso decir `insulto`, mas bien quería referirse a esta manera de responder como algo _grosera_ (pero no por lo vulgar _no tiene nada, de hecho_), o le pareció una respuesta algo _exagerada_.

Comment: Ya muchos aclararon tu pregunta. Sólo para agregar que en Perú se utiliza el término informal "causa" o "pata". Normalmente va acompañado de un saludo, pero no se usa "hola" sino "habla" (del verbo hablar) como decir "que hay de nuevo" entonces es "habla causa". O si quieres remarcar que alguien es tu mejor amigo. "¡El es mi causa!" o "¡Eres mi pata!" (Todo esto en un lenguaje informal)  Espero ayude este aporte para reducir las brechas entre nosotros los hispano-hablantes. Si por ahí escuchas el término "perucho" o "este perucho", ten cuidado. Es despectivo. Pero esa es otra historia.

Comment: Partero según mi perspectiva es algo como en México decimos cómo estás guey así l creo yo y no es una ofensa es de amigos

Comment: ¿pero que quiere decir 'gracielas?'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No es un insulto como tal, más bien es una manera informal de referirse a alguien (conocido o desconocido).

En mi opinión, parcero sería el equivalente del Inglés `homie`.

Answer (score 7):

No, no es un insulto sino una forma cordial de referirse a un amigo.

Según el interesante diccionario [Bogotalogo](https://www.scribd.com/doc/94635822/Bogotalogo-Version-Digital) ("Usos, desusos y abusos del español hablado en Bogotá"):

> **Parcero**
>
> Amigo entrañable. La expresión se deriva del vocablo portugués
>   parceiro.

Y, en efecto, mirando en el diccionario [Wordreference portugués-español](http://www.wordreference.com/ptes/parceiro), nos encontramos con:

> <sup><sub>Gran diccionario español-portugués português-espanhol © 2001
>   Espasa-Calpe:</sub></sup>
>
> parceiro, a [paR'sejɾu, ɾa]   I adj igual.
>
> II m, ƒ
>
> 1. compañero m, -a ƒ.
> 2. (sócio) socio m, -a ƒ

Y usando información de primera mano proviniente del usuario colombiano [DGaleano](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/11102/dgaleano) que amablemente deja en los comentarios:

> En realidad más que sinónimo del inglés *homie* es más similar a **bro**
>   (*like in brother*) que es más familiar. Parcero no es un insulto pero
>   nunca debe usarse en situaciones formales o con personas con las que
>   no se tenga cierta familiaridad.

---

Además, también hay [quien indica que](https://www.reddit.com/r/Colombia/comments/4w3jo8/es_la_palabra_parceroa_un_insulto_en_colombia/d64akb3) viene del verbo [*parchar*](http://bogotalogo.com/wiki/index.php?title=Parchar&action=edit), que quiere decir:

> Compartir un determinado tiempo junto a uno o varios individuos.
>   Existe el serio peligro de confundir el significado de tal término con
>   el del antioqueñismo parcharse, equivalente al rumbearse bogotano.

Comment: Esta respuesta es mucho mejor que la respuesta aceptada. En realidad mas que sinónimo del inglés **homie** es mas similar a **bro** _(like in brother)_ que es mas familiar. _Parcero_ no es un insulto pero nunca debe usarse en situaciones formales o con personas con las que no se tenga cierta familiaridad.

Comment: @DGaleano como siempre, muchas gracias por la aportación. Edité mi respuesta para añadir tu comentario.

Comment: Muy seguido en Bolivia utilizamos la palabra "aparcero".

Comment: La vez anterior que estuve por aquí hablamos del significado y el uso pero no del origen porque no era parte de la pregunta. Aunque la teoría de que viene del portugués es interesante yo más bien creo que vine del mismo español [aparcero](http://dle.rae.es/?id=35BjOKs) que significa amigo, compañero, compadre, socio. Esa 'a' inicial es fácil de omitir en el uso coloquial y con el tiempo incluso desaparecer.

Answer (score 4):

No es un insulto , es un modismo muy popular en Colombia en especial en Bogotá , Cali y Medellín.

Sería el equivalente a **partner** o **bro** en inglés.

Utilízalo para saludar personas de confianza o en situaciones informales , adicionalmente también puedes usar **bacan, hermano** que son sinónimos , sin embargo no uses **parce** siempre, ya que puede ser una expresión grosera en un contexto formal.

Answer (score 2):

Me permito aclarar la duda, parce o parcero no es propiamente un insulto pero si nos incomoda mucho a algunas personas que vivimos en el exterior Cuando al escuchar nuestro acento colombiano nos dicen:

> Ahhh, usted es parcera o parcero

por el hecho de ser Colombiana o Colombiano.

En mi caso particular odio que me digan *parcera* aún siendo yo de Medellín de donde nació el término “callejero” y el que con el paso del tiempo se ha popularizado especialmente entre los hombres jóvenes.

En mi caso y en el de muchos Colombianos NO LO USAMOS y es por esa razón, que nos incomoda que pongan como sinónimo de Colombiano el *parcero* o parcera. NO no somos parceros, somos COLOMBIANOS.

Por otra parte, como Colombiana, siempre pongo el siguiente ejemplo, si usted ve novelas o películas de narcos o prepagos, siempre escuchará en ese grupo de personas la palabra parce o parcero, por ejemplo en: Rosario tijeras, la vendedora de rosas, o todas estas series de narcos más contemporáneas, sin embargo en novelas como Betty la fea, Pedro el escamoso, La ley del silencio, entre otras que sí muestran más nuestra verdadera cultura, JAMÁS SE ESCUCHA parce o parcero

Yo como mujer opino que son palabras populares y provenientes de la cultura delincuencial de Medellín que con el tiempo se han ido mal incorporando en la cultura de un grupo de personas en Antioquia y algunas otras ciudades y regiones del país y que con aprobación y difusión de Algunos artistas como Juanes que primero fue Metalero antes de cantar lo que canta ahora, se ha ido popularizando más en la gente joven, por esta razón JAMÁS escucharán a una persona adulta un poco mayor o a una persona con cierto nivel de preparación académica, hablar de esta manera

Conclusión: parcero o parce no es sinónimo de colombiano, son palabras que se han ido metiendo en la cultura de un muy marcado grupo de colombianos que no nos generalizan o no nos identifican a TODOS, así que si NO eres colombiano mi humilde opinión es que no trates a todos los colombianos de “parceros o parces” por respeto a menos que previamente se lo escuches a “ese colombiano” porque a muchos otros estos términos no nos insultan pero si nos incomodan ya que no hacen parte de nuestra verdadera cultura.

Comment: Por otra parte, como Colombiana, siempre pongo el siguiente ejemplo, si usted ve novelas o películas de narcos o prepagos, siempre escuchará en ese grupo de personas la palabra parce o parcero, por ejemplo en: Rosario tijeras, la vendedora de rosas, o todas estas series de narcos más contemporáneas, sin embargo en novelas como Betty la fea, Pedro el escamoso, La ley del silencio, entre otras  que sí muestran más nuestra verdadera cultura, JAMÁS SE ESCUCHA parce o parcero...

Comment: Yo como mujer opino que son palabras populares y provenientes de la cultura delincuencial de Medellín que con el tiempo se han ido mal incorporando en la cultura de un grupo de personas en Antioquia y algunas otras ciudades y regiones del país y que con aprobación y difusión de Algunos artistas como Juanes que primero fue Metalero antes de cantar lo que canta ahora, se ha ido popularizando más en la gente joven, por esta razón JAMÁS escucharán a una persona adulta un poco mayor o a una persona con cierto nivel de preparación académica, hablar de esta manera

Comment: Paisana :-) Adicioné tus comentarios a la respuesta. Creo que quedan mejor ahí. +1

Answer (score 1):

En español mexicano equivale a "**guey**"
Ejemplo

> "¿Qué onda guey?"
>
> "¿Qué pasó guey?"

los fresas sólo dicen "gueee"     "wueee"

Comment: Jouz, Bienvenido al Stack. No se quien te dio el voto negativo pero tal vez es por el hecho de que tu respuesta aporta pero no responde a la pregunta. Lee por favor las reglas del foro. Mi voto positivo por tu aporte.

Comment: Jouz, explica por favor ¿qué son "los fresas"?

Comment: La definición de ser una persona "fresa" gracias a mis amigos mexicanos: Persona presumida, arrogante y que hablan todo de una manera disforzada como si fueran divos(as). Normalmente aplicado en las personas que tienen mucho dinero, que hablan y actuan como un niño(a) engreído(a). El equivalente en Perú es "pituco/pituca". Aquellos que parecieran tener dinero y que físicamente fueran descendientes de gente blanca (lo que lleva al racismo en Latinoamerica) y que hablan presumidamente. Esta sería una buena pregunta para el foro. Pero efectivamente esta respuesta no va con la pregunta.

Comment: Lo que en México denominan "fresas" en Colombia es "gomelo/a"

Answer (score 1):

Realmente el término se origina en su uso actual, en comunidades residentes en las comunas de Medellín, a donde llegó mucha gente desplazada del campo, en su mayoría labriegos (donde se utilizaba en un contexto más agropecuario). Las nuevas generaciones de hijos de los desplazados sin arraigo a la tierra,algunos de ellos con vínculos con el hampa local, la incorporaron en su jerga en donde estuvo algún tiempo hasta que salió a los medios por gracia del cine principalmente, y a su vez por la exportación de un modelo de vida de los arrabales antioqueños hacia otras ciudades en donde era muy fuerte la presencia de comunidades paisas (como se les conoce a los antioqueños de manera general).  De allí a su uso extensivo por muchos en el lenguaje coloquial, sólo el tiempo lo hizo posible.

Answer (score 0):

Debido al negocio más importante de Colombia, como lo es el narcotráfico, cuya gran sede siempre fue Medellín -de donde proviene la palabra "parcero"-, se deduce que es una transliteración de la palabra en inglés "partner" -compañero-, que tiene similitudes como vi en otras respuestas con el portugués, pero que no crea una asociación real cultural entre el origen de la palabra y su contexto de asimilación cultural. Para ello un ejemplo claro es la película "Rodrigo D. No futuro" grabada en la década del ochenta, donde la cresta de la popularidad del narcotráfico desplazó el producto nacional por tradición en Colombia: el café. Por ende es más una palabra de acercamiento mutuo, más que de un insulto.